# How to export KML without displacement?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml

I already browsed your FAQs, and could not come up with a good answer, I am trying to export shp files to kml to be placed on Google Earth.

On a previous version of QGIS it was as simple as right click and save-as.

When doing the same steps on QGIS 1.8 everything works fine until opened in GE.  My data is in northern Ontario, Canada, and it ends up being placed in the middle of the Arctic Ocean on GE.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, the  datas CRS is NAD-83 UTM zone 17N.  Could it be the projects CRS. is there a way to change a project CRS. On a previous version of QGIS I had no problems, but seem to be running into difficulties on 1.8.

Comment: Your data needs to be in Lat/Lng for Export - can you project the data first then try.

Answer (score 5):

It still is as simple as rightclick -> Save as, but make sure to set the CRS of the **destination file** to WGS84. It has nothing to do with the **Project** CRS, which can be anything else.